# How to change spinner on splash screen in ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, spinner, splash-screen

I want to change default spinner on splash screen in android plateform.
Default spinner is circle and i need bubble spinner.
Is their any way to change spinner on splash screen?

Comment: You need to modify splash screen plugin code for android platform.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to change config file as:

```
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000" />
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="true" />
<preference name="ShowSplashScreen" value="true" />
```

after that go to app.html and type:

```
<div *ngIf="showSplash">
  <div class="spinner"></div>
</div>


<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>
```

Your app.component.ts should looks like this:

```
import { timer } from 'rxjs/observable/timer';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {

  // ...omitted

  showSplash = true; // <-- show animation

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {

      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();  // <-- hide static image

      timer(3000).subscribe(() => this.showSplash = false) // <-- hide animation after 3s
    });
  }
}]
```

And also you can add some styles to your spinner from app.scss like this:

```
.spinner{
  width:4em;
  height:4em;
  background:#a1a2a1;
  border-radius:50%;
  margin:5em auto;
  border:.3em solid transparent;
  -webkit-animation:glow 1s ease infinite;
  -moz-animation:glow 1s ease infinite;
  -o-animation:glow 1s ease infinite;
  animation:glow 1s ease infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes glow {
0%{
  box-shadow:0 0 0 .4em #a1a2a1,
  0 0 0 .1em #a1a2a1;
  -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
}
50%{border-top-color:#605556;}
100%{
  box-shadow:0 0 0 .4em #a1a2a1,
  0 0 0 3.6em transparent;
}
@-moz-keyframes glow {
0%{
  box-shadow:0 0 0 .4em #a1a2a1,
  0 0 0 .1em #a1a2a1;
  -moz-transform:rotate(360deg);
}
50%{border-top-color:#605556;}
100%{
  box-shadow:0 0 0 .4em #a1a2a1,
  0 0 0 3.6em transparent;
}
@-o-keyframes glow {
0%{
  box-shadow:0 0 0 .4em #a1a2a1,
  0 0 0 .1em #a1a2a1;
  -o-transform:rotate(360deg);
}
50%{border-top-color:#605556;}
100%{
  box-shadow:0 0 0 .4em #a1a2a1,
  0 0 0 3.6em transparent;
}
@keyframes glow {
0%{
  box-shadow:0 0 0 .4em #a1a2a1,
  0 0 0 .1em #a1a2a1;
  transform:rotate(360deg);
}
50%{border-top-color:#605556;}
100%{
  box-shadow:0 0 0 .4em #a1a2a1,
  0 0 0 3.6em transparent;
}

}
```

Answer (score -1):

enter code hereYou can make change using this code

```
<preference name="SplashScreenSpinnerColor" value="#242424"/>
```

after that go to app.html and type:

Comment: I want to change splash screen spinner bubble instead of circle. Not a spinner color.